# How to read a timestamp?

Tags: time, timestamp

This is an incredibly dumb question, but I'm struggling to understand.

I have a timestamp:

```
 2017-02-03T06:16:59.094-08:00
```

When was this timestamp in UTC? Was it `2017-02-03 14:16:59.094` or  `2017-02-02 06:16:59.094`?

In other words, does the `-08:00` at the end mean that this is a local timestamp and that the timezone is 8 hours behind UTC? (`2017-02-03 14:16:59.094`)

Or does it just mean that the timestamp is UTC, but that it was recorded in a timezone 8 hours behind UTC?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. It's a cryptic notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That timestamp has a timezone *offset* that is telling you what time it was *and* the UTC offset. With no offset it becomes `2017-02-03T14:16:59.094-00:00`.

> In other words, does the -08:00 at the end mean that this is a local timestamp and that the timezone is 8 hours behind UTC? (2017-02-03 14:16:59.094)
>
> Or does it just mean that the timestamp is UTC, but that it was recorded in a timezone 8 hours behind UTC?

In a way, both. I think there's a misunderstanding about what constitutes a UTC timestamp. Every UTC timestamp comes with an offset from ["zulu"](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) time.

Answer (score 7):

If you want UTC time, then add 8 hours.  The time you see is in local time.

Here is how it works:

> Time offsets from UTC The offset from UTC is appended to the time in
>   the same way that 'Z' was above, in the form ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or
>   ±[hh]. So if the time being described is one hour ahead of UTC, such
>   as the time in Berlin during the winter, the zone designator would be
>   "+01:00", "+0100", or simply "+01". To represent a time behind UTC the
>   offset is negative. For example, the time in New York during standard
>   (not daylight saving) hours is UTC−05:00 and the zone designator would
>   then be "−05:00", "−0500", or simply "−05". For other time offsets see
>   List of UTC time offsets. To represent a negative offset, ISO 8601
>   specifies using either a hyphen–minus or a minus sign character. If
>   the interchange character set is limited and does not have a minus
>   sign character, then the hyphen–minus should be used. ASCII does not
>   have a minus sign, so its hyphen–minus character (code is 45 decimal
>   or 2D hexadecimal) would be used. If the character set has a minus
>   sign, then that character should be used. Unicode has a minus sign,
>   and its character code is U+2212 (2212 hexadecimal); the HTML
>   character entity invocation is −.
>
> The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z",
>   "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30". Nautical time zone letters
>   are not used with the exception of Z. To calculate UTC time one has to
>   subtract the offset from the local time, e.g. for "15:00−03:30" do
>   15:00 − (−03:30) to get 18:30 UTC.
>
> An offset of zero, in addition to having the special representation
>   "Z", can also be stated numerically as "+00:00", "+0000", or "+00".
>   However, it is not permitted to state it numerically with a negative
>   sign, as "−00:00", "−0000", or "−00". The section dictating sign usage
>   (section 3.4.2 in the 2004 edition of the standard) states that a plus
>   sign must be used for a positive or zero value, and a minus sign for a
>   negative value. Contrary to this rule, RFC 3339, which is otherwise a
>   profile of ISO 8601, permits the use of "-00", with the same
>   denotation as "+00" but a differing connotation.[29]
>
> ISO 8601 permits the hyphen (-) to be used as the minus (−) character
>   when the character set is limited.[30] In contrast, RFC 3339
>   explicitly requires the hyphen (-) symbol to represent negative
>   offsets and does not allow for use of the minus (−) symbol.[31]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601